# How to solve a duplicate div issue while using ajax and pushstate in Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pushstate

I have an isue with implementing an ajax in Wordpress site. I found a function on

http://www.franckmaurin.com/how-to-use-html5-history-with-wordpress-jquery/

and I tried to implement it in my Wordpress theme. I changed #main from a source code to .container_right, to adjust function for use in my theme. I almost succeeded, but when I click on any link in menu .container_right fades out, then fades in, as stated in function, but also is being duplicated. You can check that on

[www.trzywu.pl/trzywu](http://www.trzywu.pl/trzywu)

when clicking through menu links.

PS. It also breaks all existing jQuery plugins on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found my own solution. I wrapped .container_right with a .container_right_wrapper and changed .container_right in function to .container_right_wrapper, then I added some css and everything seem to be working.